# Why is the negative rail oscillating in this TPS65130 based design?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I designed a board with +-10V dual rail supply that are generated by a [TPS65130](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS65130). The design is loosely based on the reference schematic and layout. I had to move some components around due to board dimensions.

[image]
[image]
 When supply power is applied the positive output is stable at +10V, but the negative oscilates between -26V and -10V. It seems the feedback pin experiences a spike as soon as the output reaches -10V.

Scope screen capture shows the output of the negative rail(Yellow) and the voltage at FBN(Feedback negative) pin. After assembling the board I realized the trace for FBN is too long and goes under the switching diode and I bypassed this with a short piece of wire, but this didn't seem to make a difference in the behavior.

[image]

Comment: What's your load? Any minimum load requirement?

Comment: I can’t recall seeing a minimum load requirements. However I tried with a 1.5k load with no change in he output behavior

Comment: Why is FBN not a copy of output voltage with added offset? How’s your Vref? Is Vin ducking during startup? Why 100 ohm for R507?

Comment: I tested again with a supply with higher current capacity and it drew way too much current. (over 3A). I think there's a bigger problem than just the negative rail

Comment: Hi @chamod I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?